# Showing an arrow on a particular list item click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have used the right arrow of font awesome icon.

I want to slide it down always from the first list item to the clicked list item. I have tried it using jQuery but it slide from the last clicked item not always from the first list item.

Comment: Please include your non working code, and an example of the expected end result ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: I don't get understand how do i attach my code. I have to attach whole html/css code or only non-working html/css code....

Comment: Try to minimize the code to the bits needed to reproduce the problem. If you can create a runable demo using snippet, that would be great.